# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField does not populate options from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a maintenance project in Django. Following is a Class which creates a form for adding a business in the application.

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['trainers'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'select-menu fl'

    name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=70, error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the business title'},widget=forms.TextInput({'placeholder':_('Untitled Business'),'autocomplete':'off','onkeyup':'string_to_slug(this.value)'}))
    slug = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=70, error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the business slug'},widget=forms.TextInput({'class':'default-url tttxt-w','style':'width:152px;','title':_('Business Slug'),'autocomplete':'off','style':'padding: 0pt; width: 237px;','onkeyup':'string_to_slug(this.value)'}))
    description = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=5000,widget=forms.Textarea({'class':'textField long'}),error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the description'})
    trainers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                              queryset=Business.objects.filter(
                                              Q(categories__parent_cat__name='Trainers') | Q(categories__name='Trainers') | Q(categories__parent_cat__parent_cat__name='Trainers')).distinct()
                                              )

    achievements = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=5000,widget=forms.Textarea({'class':'textField long' ,'style':'width:567px;','class':'textField long'}),label='Achievements/Certificates')
    years_of_experience = forms.FloatField(required=False)
    price = forms.FloatField(required=False)
```

The issue is with the Trainers field in the form. I'm creating Trainers field in the template using:

```
<div class="field select-field">  
  <div class="label">
    <label>
      {% trans 'Trainers' %}
    </label>
   </div> 
  <div class="value">
    {{form.trainers}}               
  </div>  
</div>
```

This Trainers field is showing a strange behavior, it populates data when I restart the apache server for some time and then after sometime it starts showing a blank dropdown. Then again on restarting server it populates data. What can be the possible issue? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using PostgreSQL database and I'm still facing this issue. Not sure what is causing this strange behavior though.

**EDIT 2**:

Can this query:

```
    queryset=Business.objects.filter(
Q(categories__parent_cat__name='Trainers') | Q(categories__name='Trainers') |Q(categories__parent_cat__parent_cat__name='Trainers')).distinct()
```

might cause this issues (though I'm not able to find any issues with this)?